# How to change response body in intercept (Using retrofit 2)

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp

I read thousand of answers and try to a lot of way but doesn't work.
I really need to change response body when get "401". Because server response is different from other general response when unauthorized.

I'm using retrofit 2. To catch response i'm using Interceptor:

```
                Request original = chain.request();
                Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                        .header("authorization", getAccessToken(context));
                Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                Response response= chain.proceed(request);
                if (response.code()==401) {
                    MediaType contentType = response.body().contentType();
                    ResponseBody body = ResponseBody.create(contentType, CommonFunctions.getUnAuthorizedJson(context).toString());
                    return response.newBuilder().body(body).build();
                }else{
                    return response;
                }
```

But still body doesn't change on client.enque method.

Answer (score 0):

You can change body in this way, but Retrofit will eventually see 401 and throw HttpException with standart message, what can be misleading

check that you get your body right:

```kotlin
val errorConverter: Converter<ResponseBody, ErrorResponse> =
        retrofit.responseBodyConverter(
            ErrorResponse::class.java,
            emptyArray()
        )

val errorResponse = httpException
            .response()
            ?.errorBody()
            ?.let (errorConverter::convert)
```